# Creating / Configuring Firewall using iptables

Tags: iptables, apache-2.4, firewall, centos7, httpd

I want to set firewall using iptables.

The server is operating httpd service (httpd) The OS is Centos7, and below information is after install iptables-services, and start iptables without modify anything.

```
[root@iptables ~]# iptables -nL --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2    ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
4    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:22
5    REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

AS you can see, in INPUT chain, Line num3, it seems server any opened.

But access to web page via browser is not working.

Is there anything i have to set?

as output of `iptables-save` (taken from the comment):

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Sep 16 13:41:53 2021
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [527:50260]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Sep 16 13:41:53 2021
```

Comment: Please, show output of `iptables-save`. It is painful to decipher how iptables -L displays things. For example, in your lines may be additional matches or commands, which aren't displayed this way and so on.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your reply.
Finally i figured out the cause .
After command iptables-save, I got the cuase.

Again, Thank you for your help.
I Really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, `iptables -L` hide the additional match, but `iptables-save` showed the naked truth. Your rule #3 matches only for `lo` — a loopback interface. This firewall only accepts connections to tcp/22 (SSH) from outside.

The simplest resolution will be:

```
iptables -I INPUT 4 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 5 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

You can additionally filter with conntrack and combine both rules into a single with multiport:

```
iptables -I INPUT 4 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "HTTP/HTTPS service"
```

Notice also the comment I added. Use comments for *each* rule and some day later you'll thank me for this advice, if your firewall grows to say more than 50 rules.

Don't use `-m state`. This is obsolete. It really uses `-m  conntrack` under the hood, and it is more transparent to spell it like this explicitely.

Don't use `iptables -L`. As you've seen, it's output looks "prettier", and here advantages end, but also it fails to present all the needed details. The output of `iptables-save` looks less pretty, but it shows all the finest details, so always use the latter.